# VBA Run-Time Error 1004 After 29738 Rows

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

Good Day everyone. I'm new to VBA and was working with the following code to figure out how to query multiple tables. I would like the code to go to 100000 rows but I wanted to see how far it could actually run. Sadly, after the 29714th row, it gave me : Run-Time error 1004 'Application-defined or object-defined error'. I don't have a clue as to what is wrong other than the loop parameters might be too big. Any ideas?

```
Sub Data()

Dim qtb As New QueryTable
Dim url1 As String
Dim i As Long

For i = 2 To 540602 Step 24
url1 = Sheet2.Range("A" & i)

Set qtb = Sheet2.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & url1, Destination:=Range("B" & i))
    qtb.WebTables = "5"
    qtb.FieldNames = True
    qtb.RowNumbers = False
    qtb.FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    qtb.PreserveFormatting = True
    qtb.RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    qtb.BackgroundQuery = False
    qtb.RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    qtb.SavePassword = False
    qtb.SaveData = False
    qtb.AdjustColumnWidth = False
    qtb.RefreshPeriod = 0
    qtb.WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
    qtb.WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    qtb.WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    qtb.WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    qtb.WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    qtb.WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    qtb.WebDisableRedirections = False
    qtb.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
  Next i
  MsgBox ("X")
  End Sub
```

Comment: I would have guessed that trying to create 4166 querytables on a sheet is going to fail one way or another. Looks like you've proved it!

Comment: I deserve that. But how do I copy/paste the table data, i.e. B2:M25,B26:M49, ect. and move to the next URL so I only have one quertytable running at a time?

Comment: I would re-write your question to define how you'd want that to work. A different sheet for every copy? If not, how should they be arranged. But first, try doing what you want in the macro recorder and then tweaking the results. Since you know beforehand the address of the results, a simple copy and paste (perhaps as values?) to another sheet or whatever should do it. Then use the macro recorder again and try changing its connection in DATA>Connections.

Comment: And just an SO-related tip. When replying to a comment, do like "@DougGlancy". That way the person your replying to will be notified (although the system was smart enough to let me know this time).

Comment: @Doug Glancy I was thinking of calling the querytable as-is and then copy/pasting it onto say Sheet 1 but in the same position. Then deleting the querytable. Then just repeating the process for the next URL but still pasting on Sheet 1. But you lost me on the data>connections.

Comment: @DougGlancy I've tried and tried again with cutting off the connections and closing the Query table but I can't get it to work past 29714. I've set the start point to 29738 but it continues with the 1004 error which makes me assume it's a declaration error of some sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with. As suggested in the comments, I create the full QueryTable the first time around. After that, I just change the connection to the next cell. The web addresses are now in each row, not every 24. The code steps through them and copies the output to a new sheet for each one. My testing involved only two sites. I don't know how many it will let you create before failing:

```
Sub Data()
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim qtb As QueryTable
Dim url1 As String
Dim i As Long

Set ws = ActiveSheet 'or ws if you prefer
For i = 2 To 3 'links are in each row
    url1 = ws.Range("A" & i)
    If i = 2 Then
        Set qtb = ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & url1, Destination:=ws.Range("B1"))
        With qtb
            .WebTables = "5"
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .BackgroundQuery = True
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
            .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
            .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
            .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
            .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
            .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
            .WebDisableRedirections = False
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With
    Else
        qtb.Connection = "URL;" & url1
        qtb.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End If
    ws.Copy after:=ws.Parent.Worksheets(ws.Parent.Worksheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Columns(1).EntireColumn.Delete
Next i
End Sub
```